# edittext validation which will only allow number and ":" symbol

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need a edit text validation which will only allow **number** and **:** symbol.and length should not be more than 5 char.And most I am creating this edittext pragmatically

```
    final EditText timeVisited = new EditText(this);
    timeVisited.setId(20);
    timeVisited.setText(Tm);
    timeVisited.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    timeVisited.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
    timeVisited.setHint("eg. 14:30");
    timeVisited.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    timeVisited.setSingleLine(false);
    timeVisited.setLines(1);
    timeVisited.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.text_bg);
    customerToCatchTblRow.addView(timeVisited);// add the column to the table row here
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params5 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)timeVisited.getLayoutParams();
    params5.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
    timeVisited.setLayoutParams(params5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:digits` attribute for filtering symbols:

```
<EditText
    android:digits="0123456789:"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

or programmatically:

```
 editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789:"));
```

Answer (score 1):

use [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html). Code can be something like this

```
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i))
                        && source.charAt(i) != ':') {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    timeVisited.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

And to limit the lenght in xml of edittext use

```
android:maxLength="5"
```

Comment: It says **The type new InputFilter(){} must implement the inherited abstract method InputFilter.filter(CharSequence, int, int, Spanned, int, int)** at InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

Comment: may be you are using this in wrong place.. use the code in oncreate for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it programmatically sets the digits allowed for the EditText for validation purpose, the alphabets/numbers/symbols can be mentioned in which the user can enter only those characters

```
timeVisited.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789:"));
```

For setting maxlength via code,

```
int maxLength = 5;
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
timeVisited.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Let me know if that worked.

Comment: It's opening a number keypad which don't have the sign

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `EditText` for getting time, Use `TimePicker` instead.